# Disable scroll effect when navigating to a new location in a file?

Tags: goland

I just started using GoLand. (I have the vim emulation installed, in case that matters.) When I navigate to a new location in a file using search, going to a specific line, etc., I would like for the editor to just redraw the screen instead of appearing to scroll there. Is there some way to control that? Scrolling would be OK when only moving a short distance. I'm running GoLand 2022.3.2 on a mac running macOS 13.2.

Comment: Will it be better if you disable _Smooth Scrolling_ in _Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | Appearance_?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but no, smooth scrolling doesn't make any difference.